# Authentication for Web Reference Fails - Returns Error 405

Tags: vb.net, web-services, authentication

I'm trying to setup a connection to a web service for Purolator tracking (Purolator is a shipping company in Canada). The web service URL https://devwebservices.purolator.com/EWS/V1/Tracking/TrackingService.asmx

I've signed up for, and received a development key and development password. When I go to add the web reference in Visual Studio, I am repeatedly asked for my username and password. I type them in several times, and eventually it gives up and provides me with this error:

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
>   The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.

Apparently I need to authenticate to the web service using Basic HTTP Authentication, and I'm guessing the username/password box that pops up in Visual Studio doesn't do that type of authentication?

My development key and password definitely work though. I tried them in a PHP app, and it connects just fine.

Any idea how I can add this web service to a VB.net project? I was also provided with a local WSDL file. I can't add this file as a web reference, but I can add it as a service reference. Adding it as a service reference doesn't to provide access to the TrackingService(), which is what I need to create an instance of.

Any ideas? I've managed to get other (more simple) web references working in VB.net, but I've never had to implement one with authentication before.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your web browser put in the URL to obtain the WSDL (use your credentials): https://devwebservices.purolator.com/EWS/V1/Tracking/TrackingService.asmx?wsdl
2. Copy the contents and save the file as PurolatorWS.wsdl.
3. Add a Web Reference in your project, but instead of pointing to the URL, point it to the WSDL file you saved locally.
4. Make sure you set the URL Property before calling any methods to set the proper URL.  Ideally use a Config setting so that you can point to different environments without changing code.

   Dim objWebService As New PurolatorWS()

   objWebService.Url = "https://devwebservices.purolator.com/EWS/V1/Tracking/TrackingService.asmx"

Comment: That did the trick. Manual setting the URL with objWebService.Url is what fixed the problem. By default, the WSDL points to https://webservices.purolator.com/EWS/V1/Tracking/TrackingService.asmx which is the production web service (which I don't have a key for). Manual setting it to https://devwebservices.purolator.com/EWS/V1/Tracking/TrackingService.asmx" allows me to connect.